# File reading problem

Tags: c++, file

I have this binary file with showing the correct value when I opened the file using HexView.

4c 60 02 aa b4 c2 d1 e3 1a 01 00 00 8c 01 00 00
f5 01 00 00 52 02 00 00 bd 02 00 00 20 03 00 00
32 03 00 00 59 03 00 00

When I uses fread to read the 40 bytes data into a char buffer, it failed. From 9th byte data onwards, all the read back data is 0x00.

```
int main()
{
    FILE *stream;
    char flag[40]={0};
    size_t numread = 0;
    UINT theme = 0;

    if ((stream = fopen("alignment.bin", "r")) != NULL)
    {
        numread = fread(&flag, 1, 40, stream);

        fclose(stream);
    }
    else
    {
        cout << "File open failed" << endl;
    }
    system ("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Are you using Windows by any chance?  The 9th byte is `1a` (a.k.a Ctrl+Z) which may be considered an end-of-file in Windows.

Comment: Yes, is in Windows environment. Any idea what is the meaning of Ascii 0x1a?

Comment: it means end-of-file for Windows text files.  I had that in my answer but I deleted the after realizing that Mystical was first with the "rb" by a couple minutes! See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Control-Z

Answer (score 9):

Try using `"rb"` instead of `"r"`. There might be some weird text formatting issues.

Specifying the `b` makes it read in pure binary with no formatting.

Comment: So, by using "rb", it will make the reading purely in binary, ignoring those special character in Ascii map?

Comment: The special bytes will not be "ignored", but no action taken on them.

Answer (score 0):

0x1A == 26 == *ctrl-Z* == EOF.

If you read in text mode, the stream consider the flow finished after that point (what follow is "rubbish for other transmissions").